# openypyxl - strange behavior - sometimes it can write data to sheet, sometimes not

Tags: openpyxl

I found very strange behavior when trying export data to worksheet using openpyxl.

The problem is in the condition (if record['week'] == '01') If I set anything other than "01" there, then even if the condition is met (the record was found in the data and control print was printed sucessfully) the data will not be written to the cell. When I set it to "01" it executes without any problems and data are written to the cell correctly. Any idea? I am totaly frustraded, already spent few hours about this issue with no idea how to continue. Please tell me i am dumb and overlooked something. Tried to convert that values "01", "02" to integers but it is not working too. Thank You.

```
for i, record in enumerate(data_q_monday):
            
            if record['day'] == 'Monday' and record['month'] == 'January' and record['week'] in ['01', '02', '03', '04']:
                
                if record['week'] == '02': # <<< HERE i found the problem
                        print(f"Week {record['week']} is valid to write to {sheet}.")
                                                
                        row_index = 25 + i

                        cell = sheet.cell(row=row_index, column=4)
                        
                        sheet.cell(row=row_index, column=4, value="some data")
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but "01" vs "02" can tell that this is not the case about wrong data type. Both are strings and need to be.

Comment: Nothing wrong with the code per se. It wouldn't matter what the criteria is, if the line `sheet.cell(row=row_index, column=4, value="some data")` is run the cell will be written. We don't know what the input data is so potentially the row written to could be any from 25 to the end of the sheet, or possibly even off the end of the sheet. No idea if you are just not looking in the right place on the sheet. Either way you will need to do some basic debugging, do you have an IDE if not then print statements to see which cell the value is being written to.

Comment: Likely the case is unless the criteria is '01' the check is False and the cell is not written to. Is there any purpose for the line ` cell = sheet.cell(row=row_index, column=5)`?

Comment: It's almost certain that the criteria are not being met. Please include a **few** examples of the records.

Comment: i found the problem. The problem is in the iterator. When i checked the content of "i" there was number 28546 what is the first presence of the first condition and then row_index is shifted by this number. So my solution is to clear the iterator when desired record is found. Thank you guys for help.